# Visual Studio Code snippet that inserts the method/function name?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-extensions

I am not looking for a snippet that creates a method or function, I want a snippet that inserts the name of the method/function automatically.

Precisely, I would like something like this:

```
console.log('${TM_METHODNAME}: ${1}')
```

Unfortunately, `TM_METHODNAME` is not part of the [default set of variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables).

There doesn't seem to be an extension available for that either.

Maybe a compromise would be to use `TM_SELECTED_TEXT`, although I don't understand how it works, as when typing the snippet prefix, the selected text is obviously erased.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of v1.20 you can use `CLIPBOARD` as a variable, see [v1.20 release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_20#_more-snippet-variables) so you could copy the method name first and have it ready to use in the snippet.  I think at this point that is your only option.

Comment: Then so be it!!

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend you the following Visual Studio extension.

**Turbo Console Log**

Is available [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChakrounAnas.turbo-console-log)

Some features:

Selecting the variable which is the subject of the debugging

Pressing

> CTRL + ALT + L

The log message will be inserted in the next line relative to the selected 
variable like this:

```
console.log('SelectedVariableEnclosingClassName -> SelectVariableEnclosingFunctionName -> SelectedVariable', SelectedVariable)
```

Answer (score 1):

that's sad we still don't have `$TM_METHOD_NAME` available, anyway here few snippets I use with `$WORKSPACE_NAME` and `$TM_FILENAME` to differentiate the output along with coloring:

[image]

```
   {
        "key": "cmd+alt+l",
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "when": "editorTextFocus",
        "args": {
            "snippet": "console.log(`%c[${WORKSPACE_NAME/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}] ${CLIPBOARD}`, '${2|background: lightblue; color: #444;,background: lightgreen; color: #444;,background: lightsalmon; color: #444;,background: lightcyan; color: #444;,background: lightpink; color: #444;,background: lightseagreen; color: #444;,background: lightskyblue; color: #444;,background: lightsteelblue; color: #444;,background: khaki; color: #444;,background: purple; color: white;,background: salmon; color: white;,background: blue; color: white;,background: #444; color: white;,background: green; color: white;,background: mediumvioletred; color: white;,background: blueviolet; color: white;,background: chocolate; color: white;,background: mediumvioletred; color: white;,background: brown; color: white;,background: cadetblue; color: white;,background: cornflowerblue; color: white;,background: crimson; color: white;|} padding: 3px; border-radius: 5px;');"
        }
    },
    {
        "key": "cmd+alt+e",
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "when": "editorTextFocus",
        "args": {
            "snippet": "console.groupCollapsed('$TM_FILENAME');\nError.stackTraceLimit = ${0:4};\nconsole.log(new Error('$TM_FILENAME').stack);\nconsole.groupEnd();\n"
        }
    },
    {
        "key": "cmd+alt+shift+l",
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "when": "editorTextFocus",
        "args": {
            "snippet": "console.groupCollapsed(`%c[${WORKSPACE_NAME/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}] ${CLIPBOARD}`, '${2|background: lightblue; color: #444;,background: lightgreen; color: #444;,background: lightsalmon; color: #444;,background: lightcyan; color: #444;,background: lightpink; color: #444;,background: lightseagreen; color: #444;,background: lightskyblue; color: #444;,background: lightsteelblue; color: #444;,background: khaki; color: #444;,background: purple; color: white;,background: salmon; color: white;,background: blue; color: white;,background: #444; color: white;,background: green; color: white;,background: mediumvioletred; color: white;,background: blueviolet; color: white;,background: chocolate; color: white;,background: mediumvioletred; color: white;,background: brown; color: white;,background: cadetblue; color: white;,background: cornflowerblue; color: white;,background: crimson; color: white;|} padding: 3px; border-radius: 5px;');\nconsole.log(${CLIPBOARD});\nconsole.groupEnd();\n"
        }
    },
```

drop this to `keybindings.json`